# Android Bluetooth LE scan all at once

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Is there a way to scan all bt le ibeacons in Android 4.3/4.4 without having to use startLeScan in an async way?

I'm looking for a way to get the mac address and rssi values of all that ibeacons at once.

Is there any external lib or low level way to do that?

Many thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider how the hardware works at the **radio level**.

When you call *startLeScan()*, it turns on the LE radio and it has vendor defined ON - OFF (sleep) cycles typically ranging from a few uSec to a ms.

The radio would be able to return a list of devices to the driver only after it has scanned for the relevant frequencies. This in no way can be accomplished in a *synchronous* manner. Hence you have to provide a callback - which gets fired depending upon the design: like burst of device list at the end of scan cycle OR incremental addition of devices to the list as discovery continues - Am not sure how Android does it - am speaking form a custom RTOS driver perspective

**Edit:-**
I have learnt about a design where the radio is ON all the time - off course  that would mean a considerable hit to the *power* equation - but that allows the driver or hal layer to persist a *running* list of scanned devices. The tricky situation here would be to come up with the optimal *remove from list* policy

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do that synchronously and if there is, I don't think it would be a good idea - you application would freeze, once the scan is a slow operation.